# How to deploy a python application that needs JVM to google cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, jvm

it's my first time deploying a application with Python and Flask, so i'm not sure how to properly do it. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fsIcMgUOY8&t=396s) and followed the exact steps, but i'm getting the below error.The application is pretty simple, but i'm using a package that uses `JVM`. Locally it works fine, but once i deployed, i'm getting this error

> jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file
> (libjvm.so) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable
> properly.

This route works fine

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

But the one i'm using that package throws that error.

This is my `requirements.txt`

```
Flask==2.2.2
autopep8==2.0.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
JPype1==1.4.1
konlpy==0.6.0
lxml==4.9.2
numpy==1.24.3
packaging==23.1
pycodestyle==2.10.0
```

And at my `app.yaml`, i have only this

```
runtime: python38
```

How should i deploy it on Google Cloud?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install Java? ***JPype is a Python module to provide full access to Java from 
within Python. ***

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, here in my PC everything works fine. Should i add JPype to requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the JVM shared library file (libjvm.so) is missing and suggests setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Identify the path to the Java installation on the Google Cloud environment. This can vary depending on the Linux distribution being used. Common paths are /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 or /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64.

Run the following command to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java

Verify that the JAVA_HOME variable is set correctly by running:

echo $JAVA_HOME

Also in requirements.txt try to use some old version like JPype1==1.3.0

Hope these can help out in troubleshoot.